# Not able to access data even though it exists, using Pandas dataframe, when training a deep learning model using Python3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn

I am trying to do k-fold cross validation using sklearn and using pandas dataframe. This is not working as expected. Looks like the data cannot be accessed for some reason even though it exists. The code works for some time, but is unable to complete a full epoch.

Here is the error:

```
Downloading data from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/keras-applications/resnet/resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5
94773248/94765736 [==============================] - 1s 0us/step
94781440/94765736 [==============================] - 1s 0us/step
458/610 [=====================>........] - ETA: 21s - loss: 0.1640 - accuracy: 0.1621

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

UnknownError                              Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-7-28b7c7367434> in <module>()
     60                         validation_data=valid_gen,
     61                         validation_steps=len(test_index)//valid_batch_size,
---> 62                         verbose=1)


...

UnknownError: Graph execution error:

2 root error(s) found.
  (0) UNKNOWN:  IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 271, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 642, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 1004, in generator_py_func
    values = next(generator_state.get_iterator(iterator_id))

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 830, in wrapped_generator
    for data in generator_fn():

  File "<ipython-input-4-8914ea8c1843>", line 6, in get_data_generator
    r = df.iloc[i]

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 931, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1566, in _getitem_axis
    self._validate_integer(key, axis)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1500, in _validate_integer
    raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")

IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds


     [[{{node PyFunc}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]]
     [[IteratorGetNext/_2]]
  (1) UNKNOWN:  IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 271, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 642, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 1004, in generator_py_func
    values = next(generator_state.get_iterator(iterator_id))

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 830, in wrapped_generator
    for data in generator_fn():

  File "<ipython-input-4-8914ea8c1843>", line 6, in get_data_generator
    r = df.iloc[i]

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 931, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1566, in _getitem_axis
    self._validate_integer(key, axis)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1500, in _validate_integer
    raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")

IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds


     [[{{node PyFunc}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_function_13498]
```

Here is the code that I am trying to do:

```py
# using google colab
! pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir gdown
! gdown 1_DgB2a2Q7eYJpXtKWfl4XPUgTIW1sXw1

! unzip -qq Train.zip

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob
import csv
import pandas as pd
# create a pandas data frame of images, age, gender and race


from tensorflow.keras.applications import ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
from keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Multiply, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from PIL import Image
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras import backend as K
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from tensorflow import keras
from datetime import datetime
from tensorflow import keras
from tqdm import tqdm
import pandas as pd


def get_data_generator(df, indices, batch_size=16):
    images, labels = [], []
    while True:
        for i in indices:
            # print(i," - ",end="")
            r = df.iloc[i]
            file_, label = r['file'], r['label']
            im_gray = Image.open(file_).convert('L')
            im_gray = im_gray.resize((360, 360))
            im = np.zeros(shape=(360, 360,3))

            im[:,:,0] = im_gray
            im[:,:,1] = im_gray
            im[:,:,2] = im_gray
            
            im = np.array(im) / 255.0
            images.append(im)
            new_label = label/100.0
            labels.append(new_label)
            
            if len(images) >= batch_size:
                yield np.array(images), np.array(labels)
                images, labels = [], []
  



np.random.seed(42)


EPOCHS = 1
MODEL_NAME = 'ResNet50'
IMG_SIZE = '360x360'


all_train_imgs = glob.glob('Train/*')
# print("Length of all training images = ",len(all_train_imgs))




all_training_files_name = []
all_training_perc = []

with open('Train.csv') as f:
    contents = f.readlines()


for item in contents:
    # make the changes in the folder here
    img_name = "Train/"+item.split(',')[0]
    perc_infc = float(item.split(',')[1])
    num_pat = item.split(',')[2]
    # print(img_name," - ",perc_infc," - ",num_pat)
    all_training_files_name.append(img_name)
    all_training_perc.append(perc_infc)




attributes = {'label':all_training_perc, 'file':all_training_files_name}

df_all = pd.DataFrame(attributes)
df_all = df_all.dropna()
print(df_all.head())


kf = KFold(n_splits=5)

kf.get_n_splits(all_training_files_name)


fold_no = 0

for train_index, test_index in kf.split(all_training_files_name):
    fold_no += 1

    #########################################################################################
    OUTPUT = 1
    frozen = ResNet50 (weights="imagenet", input_shape=(360,360,3), include_top=False)
    trainable = frozen.output
    trainable = Dropout(0.5)(GlobalAveragePooling2D()(trainable))
    trainable = Dense(2048, activation="relu")(trainable)
    trainable = Dense(1024, activation="relu")(trainable)
    trainable = Dense(OUTPUT, activation="sigmoid")(trainable)
    model = Model(inputs=frozen.input, outputs=trainable)

    opt = Adam(learning_rate=1e-5)
    model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError(),#loss='binary_crossentropy',
                #experimental_run_tf_function=False,
                metrics = ['accuracy']
                )
    #########################################################################################


    batch_size = 4
    valid_batch_size = 4

    df_train = df_all.loc[train_index.astype(int)] 
    df_val = df_all.loc[test_index.astype(int)] 
    

    train_gen = get_data_generator(df_train, train_index, batch_size=batch_size)
    valid_gen = get_data_generator(df_val, test_index, batch_size=valid_batch_size)


    callbacks = [
        ModelCheckpoint("./model_checkpoint", monitor='val_loss'),
        #ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.1, patience=4)
    ]

    # for storing logs into tensorboard
    logdir="logs/fit/" + datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
    tensorboard_callback = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=logdir)

    history = model.fit(train_gen,
                        steps_per_epoch=len(train_index)//batch_size,
                        epochs=EPOCHS,
                        callbacks=[tensorboard_callback,callbacks],
                        validation_data=valid_gen,
                        validation_steps=len(test_index)//valid_batch_size,
                        verbose=1)
```

Here is the code for reproducing in google colab : https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11C-GP6xCB3CCwvz6gj8gy6mTOJIc3Zld?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, there were some error in dataframe creation. For this problem, making these following changes works, just using the full dataframe.

```py
    #df_train = df_all.loc[train_index.astype(int)] 
    #df_val = df_all.loc[test_index.astype(int)] 
    

    train_gen = get_data_generator(df_all, train_index, batch_size=batch_size)
    valid_gen = get_data_generator(df_all, test_index, batch_size=valid_batch_size)
```